# no window manager running Kivy

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

Could anyone help me fix this? I have a program with Kivy but it won't start on my computer.
I attach the log file. I have tried to install almost every library in the RPM repos haha...

Running Fedora 27:

```
Linux v27.lcars-1 4.15.10-300.fc27.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 15 17:13:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have tried install SDL2 from source or from package with the same error.

```
[INFO   ] Logger: Record log in /home/rroman/.kivy/logs/kivy_18-04-23_20.txt
[INFO   ] Kivy: v1.10.1.dev0, git-ae3665c, 20180424
[INFO   ] Python: v2.7.14 (default, Mar 14 2018, 13:36:31) 
[GCC 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)]
[INFO   ] Factory: 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] OSC: using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] Window: Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] Window: Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
egl_rpi - ImportError: cannot import name bcm
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from kivy.lib.vidcore_lite import bcm, egl

sdl2 - ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/graphics/cgl_backend/cgl_gl.so: undefined symbol: glGetRenderbufferParameteriv
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 67, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 140, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 960, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 272, in create_window
    self.fullscreen, resizable, state)
  File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 125, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window
  File "kivy/graphics/cgl.pyx", line 52, in kivy.graphics.cgl.cgl_get_backend_name
  File "kivy/graphics/cgl.pyx", line 60, in kivy.graphics.cgl.cgl_get_backend_name
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "kivy/graphics/cgl_backend/cgl_glew.pyx", line 9, in init kivy.graphics.cgl_backend.cgl_glew

x11 - ImportError: No module named window_x11
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)

[INFO   ] Text: Provider: sdl2
[WARNING] stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
[WARNING] stderr:   File "./src/main.py", line 40, in <module>
[WARNING] stderr:     MainApp().run()
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 800, in run
[WARNING] stderr:     root = self.build()
[WARNING] stderr:   File "./src/main.py", line 25, in build
[WARNING] stderr:     Window.clearcolor = settings.whiteColor
[WARNING] stderr: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clearcolor'
```

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: f27, i put the info in the post.

Comment: What is your window manager? gnome?

Comment: xfce as desktop manager